# Need to create random numbers any time a call a class

Tags: python, class, random

I need help with this issue: I've created a class whose reference is a random number. The problem is this: every time a call that class, i get the same number, making pointless the use of random; is there any way to solve this?

```
import random
class dicethrow:
    result = random.randint (1,6)
a = dicethrow ()
b = dicethrow ()
```

Using this, a == b always, i need them to be different.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [random.choice not random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366047/random-choice-not-random)

Answer (score 2):

In your case `result` is a class (or static) variable - it is defined once and is the same for all instances.

Define `result` in `__init__()` method:

```
import random


class dicethrow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = random.randint(1,6)

a = dicethrow()
b = dicethrow()
print a.result
print b.result
```

See also:

- [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
class dicethrow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = random.randint(1, 6)
```

Comment: so the problem is that as soon as i create the class, every reference is created; your way, every time i call the class, it creates the number, am I right?
anyhow, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because result is a static variable, shared by all the instances of your class.

What you need here is a function:

```
import random
def dicethrow():
    return random.randint (1,6)
a = dicethrow ()
b = dicethrow ()
```